# something like google suggest example

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qlistwidget, qlineedit

i have a `qlineEdit` and a `QListWidget` i want to have something like google suggestion, when user type a text, i want to display only items with text starting with that text, but i don't know how should i do that? i think i should write a searchbox but i should call it every time user insert or delete character, i don't know if there is a better idea?

```
SearchBox(QWidget *parent = 0);
```

or is there any sample in examples like this?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can use QCompleter to provide auto completions in any Qt widget, such as QLineEdit and QComboBox. When the user starts typing a word, QCompleter suggests possible ways of completing the word, based on a word list.

An example is :

```
 QStringList wordList;
 wordList << "alpha" << "omega" << "omicron" << "zeta";

 QLineEdit *lineEdit = new QLineEdit(this);

 QCompleter *completer = new QCompleter(wordList, this);
 completer->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
 lineEdit->setCompleter(completer);
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, but i need when they type my list possible item shows, not helping complete the text

Comment: This will list possible items when you type. Try it.